# Allowing a user to edit a file without owning it in Linux

Tags: linux, nginx, permissions

I understand this has most likely been answered but for the life of me cannot figure it out.

**What is the problem?**
I'm running an nginx server and have the user "www-data" own the web server directory and all of it's contents. I run wordpress so it is important that www-data keeps ownership as if it does not, the wordpress UI will not be able to edit files. I also like to use SFTP but have disabled login for any other user besides my own. Currently, when I want to use FTP to edit files, I have to chown the wp-content directory temporarily to my personal user and then re-chown the directory back to the www-data user when finished.

**What is the intended outcome?**
Ideally, I'd like to configure the file permissions so that I may edit files within this directory without having to chown between users everytime. Is this possible or would I be better off setting my personal user as a root user?

**What have you tried?**
I've tried chown-ing the directory to a group that both www-data and my user are in. Example being:

```
chown -R :www-data /path/to/dir/wp-content/*
```

Where "www-data" is both the name of the web user, AND the name of a group that contains both users: myuser & www-data. Even after doing so, myuser is not able to edit the files within this directory.

If anyone would be kind enough to educate a fool (me) or refer to myself a proper resource, I'd be very grateful! Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a user that has associated group, named after that user. So you can do the following:

`sudo chgrp  -R YOUR_USER_NAME YOUR_FOLDER`

this should change owinging group for the data in your folder and that owning group will be your user's group

Then change the privilige for the group using:

`chmod -R g+w YOUR_FOLDER`

Comment: Security wise, is this an okay thing to do or would this be a temporary solution? I'm assuming the only downfall would be if I had multiple other users but since I only allow a single user to sign on (myself) then this would be safe?

Comment: Sure it is not secure at all. More correct solution would be to create a group. Your user should have a group named after it so you can do the same but change the owning group by `chgrp` command so that the owning group would be your user group. And then use `g+w` instead of `o+w`.

Comment: Aha okay, I may try that second solution if the first one isn't a match for me. Last question and it's a dumb one; Being a server newbie, assuming that I use the o+w file permissions, this gives access to anyone on the machine, correct? So if someone were to access the website from the web, so long as they aren't able to gain access to the machine, they shouldn't be able to write to any files / directories right? (Silly question, sorry). Edit: For clarity, I'm asking if by doing o+w, do I open myself up to any outside security vulnerabilities? (directory traversal, lfi, etc)

Comment: If a server is running under user A and it can access some file and also it has a vulnerability allowing to execute arbitrary code, that code would be running on behalf of user A and will access that file independentiy on whether the other users have the privileges or not. Using `o+w` for a certain folder does not mean you're giving the access to anyone. It only means that if anyone will somehow authenticate on your server (not by accessing a web-site but using sftp or ssh for example) they will be able to access those files.

Comment: Anyway it is always better to use "the Principle of Least Privilege" for any sensitive data residing on the computer that is exposed to the Internet.

Comment: I appreciate you for all the help and insight you have provided. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

There's already an answer, but I figure I'll give a detailed one anyway, for everyone's sake :)

> I'm running an nginx server and have the user "www-data" own the web server directory and all of it's contents

You see where it fails from the beginning, is that any sensitive files can be served by NGINX, unless denied in specifically in configuration, simply because it owns it. It's not good because it won't use `chmod` permission model as a way to control what NGINX can serve and what it cannot.

There is only one setup that is secure and *proper*, and I detail it [here](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-and-php-fpm-what-my-permissions-should-be).

Specifically, each website must have its own PHP-FPM pool, which runs by a website-specific user.

The webserver user (e.g. `www-data` or `nginx`) is the member of all website's usergroups, e.g. `nginx` is member of `wordpress` usergroup.

This allows to simply have `0750` (dirs) and `0640` (files) permissions, and have no issues at all.

Comment: Great explanation and I appreciate having the security aspects involved! Bookmarked and will begin redoing file permissions soon, thanks!